# Is there any possibility to add Apache FileVault package to provisioned Sling's files?

Tags: sling

I am using Sling Launchpad with provisioning config file. Recently I would add support for FileVault packages (that are zip files). I have added `package` type of project and add it to my provisioning file. Unfortunately, it is not supporting those file type. Did anybody has same problem, and, if isn't supporting packages at all, how to install packages during Sling startup?

I have reviewed `OSGiInstaller` class in Sling source code, and there are only installing things from `RegisteredResource` class, which is located in `RegisteredResourcesList.ser` file (some kind of binary file), but I can see only `jar` files...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's out of the box support for that in Sling, but the OSGi installer does provide the necessary hooks to support new resource types, besides bundles and configs. You'd need to implement a `ResourceTransformer` to dispatch the vlt archives, an `InstallTaskFactory` to create the relevant `InstallTask` from the files extracted from the vlt archive, and implement new task types for the vlt-specific file types.

If you want to do that it would be best to discuss the design on the [Sling dev mailing list](http://sling.apache.org/project-information.html#mailing-lists) first.

Comment: `slingstart` allows to create a `zip` entry by providing extension into particular artifact row, like `my-group/my-artifact/0.0.1/zip`, and it is included into `/resources/0/install` folder in jar file. From this point, it needs to create (as you wrote) `ResourceTransformer` to set resource type to `content-package`. `InstallTaskFactory` has to implement an install method and that is it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that if you create something like this the Sling community would most probably be ready to accept it as a contribution.

Comment: @DawidPura have you implemented this successfully ? because I run into the same problem, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this. The `com.composum.sling.core/composum-sling-osgi-package-installer/${composum.version}` bundle have implementations of `ResourceTransformer` and `InstallTaskFactory` services. If you add this bundle to your provisioning model (next to other composum bundles) and add `com.composum.core.pckginstall` to `LoginAdminWhitelist` then you will be able to install zip packages during creating Sling instance.